# Array deleting its previous content when I try to add more, in C# unity

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I've recently started coding C# in unity to learn. There is still much code that I don't understand, arrays beeing one of them.

I'm trying to make a code that finds objects, counts them, and then store their positions in a Vector3 array.

```
GameObject[] ExistingObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Parts");
float CountObjects = ExistingObjects.Length;

for (int i = 0; i < CountObjects; i++)
{
    float ObjectPositionX = ExistingObjects[i].transform.position.x;
    float ObjectPositionZ = ExistingObjects[i].transform.position.z;
    Vector3[] ObjectPositions = new[] { new Vector3(ObjectPositionX, 0, ObjectPositionZ) };
}
```

When I have just one object in the scene, everything works. When I add more than that, it gets the first Vector3 from the first object it finds, and then deletes it when it puts the second Vector3 into the array. So all I'm left with (no matter how many objects I place in the scene) is ObjectPositions[0].

As I've already said, I'm fairly new to C# coding.

Comment: Use ArrayLists or Generics instead

Comment: You should declare ObjectPositions _outside_ the for loop. Then, adding each element _inside_ of it. Actually, you're re-declaring it at each iteration, overwriting it each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a new variable `ObjectPositions` in the loop. You should create this variable outside the loop and only add a `Vector3` to this variable inside the loop.

This looks something like this:

```
Vector3[] ObjectPositions = new Vector3[CountObjects];
for (int i = 0; i < CountObjects; i++)
{
    float ObjectPositionX = ExistingObjects[i].transform.position.x;
    float ObjectPositionZ = ExistingObjects[i].transform.position.z;
    ObjectPositions[i] = new Vector3(ObjectPositionX, 0, ObjectPositionZ);
}
```

Comment: @NitroFray if this worked, would you mind marking this solution as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use Generics instead

```
GameObject[] ExistingObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Parts");
float CountObjects = ExistingObjects.Length;
List<ObjectPositions> Vector3 = new List<ObjectPositions>();
for (int i = 0; i < CountObjects; i++)
{
    float ObjectPositionX = ExistingObjects[i].transform.position.x;
    float ObjectPositionZ = ExistingObjects[i].transform.position.z;
    Vector3.Add(new Vector3(ObjectPositionX, 0, ObjectPositionZ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
GameObject[] ExistingObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Parts");
Vector3[] ObjectPositions = new Vector3[ExistingObjects.Length]

for(int i = 0; i < ObjectPositions.Length; i++)
{
   ObjectPositions[i] = ExistingObjects[i].transform.position;
   ObjectPositions[i].y = 0;
}
```